# Symfony 5 form not submitted when a list contains a placeholder

Tags: forms, symfony, placeholder, choicefield

I have a form with different lists like this :

```
 $builder
      ->add('seatsNumber', ChoiceType::class, [
                                                        'placeholder' => 'choose.number.seats.placeholder',
                                                        'choices' => [
                                                                        '1.seat.choice' => 1,
                                                                        '2.seats.choice' => 2,
                                                                        '3.seats.choice' => 3,
                                                                        '4.seats.choice' => 4,
                                                                        '5.seats.choice' => 5,
                                                                        '6.seats.choice' => 6,
                                                                        '7.seats.choice' => 7,
                                                                        '8.seats.choice' => 8,
                                                                        '9.seats.choice' => 9,
                                                                        '10.seats.choice' => 10
                                                                     ],
                                                        'attr' => [
                                                                    'class' => 'select'
                                                                  ],
                                                        'label' => 'seats.number.label',
                                                        'multiple' => false,
                                                        'required' => true
                                                      ]
                 )
```

This is the generated HTML :

```
<select id="vehicle_seatsNumber" name="vehicle[seatsNumber]" required="required" class="select form-control" tabindex="-1">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Choose the number of seats</option>
  <option value="1">1 seat</option>
  <option value="2">2 seats</option>
  <option value="3">3 seats</option>
  <option value="4">4 seats</option>
  <option value="5">5 seats</option>
  <option value="6">6 seats</option>
  <option value="7">7 seats</option>
  <option value="8">8 seats</option>
  <option value="9">9 seats</option>
  <option value="10">10 seats</option>
</select>
```

When I try to submit the form without having select a choice (placeholder is shown), the form isn't submitted and no one message is shown.

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts

Comment: When I remove the placeholder, it's all right : the form is correctly submitted. As soon as I add the placeholder attribute, the form isn't submitted without message.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Could you share a minimum working example that triggers the problem, such that others could reproduce it?

Comment: I don't complete the field in the form. I push on the submit button. The form isn't submitted (ok because the control is required) but I don't have an error message.

Comment: In my controller, I did this dump : dump($form->isSubmitted()); Before the click on the submit button, the result is 'false'. After the click, I don't have a new result because the page is not reloaded.

Comment: I added a javascript on the submit button click to show in the console the value of the number seats field : the value is shown and is null. If I add the same javascript on the form submit event, the value is not shown. The form is therefore not submitted. No one error message is displayed by Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display validation error, you should consider using [constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html)

```
$builder->add('seatsNumber', ChoiceType::class, [ 'constraints' => [
    new NotNull(),
    new NotBlank()
] ])
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your interest. The problem was the HTML validation on the "required" attribute wasn't worked. That was due to a custom select library. I resolved the problem adding the "required" class to the select fields form in Twig. By example : {{ form_row(form.seatsNumber, { 'attr': {'class': 'required'}}) }}. Now, I have a message when the field isn't filled.